# How to find the remaining % values in a array given a certain set of values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider we have a array of objects:

```
let online = [{start:4,end:8},{start:19,end:34},{start:65,end:80}];
```

I want to infer another array from this data:

```
let offline = [{start:0,end:3},{start:9,end:18},{start:35,end:64},{start:81,end:100}];
```

The max number can be 100 and min can be 0.

Comment: What if the input data is not in order? would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
let online = [
  { start: 4, end: 8 },
  { start: 19, end: 34 },
  { start: 65, end: 80 },
];

let _start = 0;
const result = [];
online.forEach((on) => {
  const { start, end } = on;
  if (_start !== start) {
    result.push({
      start: _start,
      end: start - 1,
    });
  }
  _start = end + 1;
});
if (_start < 100) {
  result.push({
    start: _start,
    end: 100,
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some custom logic like the one below. I'm also addind a sort function just to be safe regarding the order of elements in the array.

```js
let online = [
  { start: 4, end: 8 },
  { start: 19, end: 34 },
  { start: 65, end: 80 },
];
const onlineSort = online.sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start);
let currentIndex = onlineSort[0].start < 0 ? onlineSort[0].start < 0 : 0;
const offLine = [];
onlineSort.forEach((node) => {
  offLine.push({
    start: currentIndex,
    end: node['start'] - 1
  });
  currentIndex = node['end'] + 1;
});
console.log(online);
console.log(offLine);
```

Comment: Be aware that this will give unwanted results if start is 0 and it's missing the remaining offline data `{ start: 81, end: 100 }`

Comment: May be. I have updated the answer with that edge case aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that utilizes reduce (and the online array) to accumulate the offline ranges.

Here it is expanded. It's a one-liner in the snippet

```
let offline = online.reduce((b, a, i) => 
   // set up our reducer and include the index i
   [...b, {start: online[i].end + 1, end: i < online.length - 1 ? online[i + 1].start - 1 : 100}], 
   // return a spread of the current accumulating array b, along with the next object, that gets it's start and end values from the online array using the same index
   [{start: 0, end: online[0].start - 1}]);
   // start off our array with the first set of values.
   .filter(f=>f.end>0)
   // incase the online array starts at zero, this will remove and invalid entries
```

```js
const getOffline = (online) =>  online.reduce((b, a, i) => [...b, {start: online[i].end + 1, end: i < online.length - 1 ? online[i + 1].start - 1 : 100}], [{start: 0, end: online[0].start - 1}]).filter(f=>f.end>0);

console.log(getOffline([{start:4,end:8},{start:19,end:34},{start:65,end:80}]))
console.log(getOffline([{start:0,end:8},{start:19,end:34},{start:65,end:80}]))
```